# Inserting a value from dropdownlist to database from another table

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I have two tables in my project for students activity. ( one table(name : evidall) where I store my subjects(in my code they are on foreign language  named 'predmet' ) and I have another table( name : evid_record) where I have a script to put in the data about students and I have a dropdownlist that is pulling the names of the subjects from the  first table(evidall). I manage to make it pull the data to the drop downlist, but when I select any subject in the dropdownlist, it wont save it to the second table(evid_record). Im trying to make this for for days, and I really don't know what am I doing wrong. Everything that I found online is for the direct values that are written in the dropdownlist, but my case is a bit more specific than that..

**Here's the code for my DDL and the form :**

```
    <body>

   <div class="forma">
       <form action="snimipodatkestud.php" method="Post">
           <fieldset>

    <span class="FieldInfo">Ime:</span><br><input type="text" name="imes" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Prezime:</span><br><input type="text" name="prezimes" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Broj indeksa: </span><br><input type="text" name="indeksbr" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Predmet: <br>
                    <select name="zpredmet">

                             <option>Choose one..</option>
                                       <option name="izpredmet" value="
                      <?php   

                                $ViewQuery="SELECT epredmet FROM evidall";
                                $Execute= mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);

                                          while($datarows=mysqli_fetch_array($Execute)){
                                                echo "<option value=\"\">" . $datarows['epredmet'] . "</option>";
    }                       
                                             ?>" ></option>
                              <br></select><br>

    <span class="FieldInfo">Teorija kolokvijum:</span><br><input type="text" name="teorija" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Zadaci kolokvijum: </span><br><input type="text" name="zadaci" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Aktivnost: </span><br><input type="text" name="akt" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Prisustvo: </span><br><input type="text" name="pris" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Seminarski rad: </span><br><input type="text" name="semrad" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Domaci rad: </span><br><input type="text" name="domrad" value=""><br>

              <div class="klgg">
   <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upisi"><br>
             </div>

              <br><?php echo $NEuspehupis; ?><br>
               <br><?php echo $uspehupis; ?><br> 
           </fieldset>


       </form>


   </div>




</body>
```

And here is the insert part :

```
<?php include("konekcija.php");?>
<?php

    global $connection;
    global $uspehupis;
    global $NEuspehupis;

$ime = $prezime = $izpredmet = $teorija = $zadaci = $akt = $pris = $semrad = $domrad = $indeksbr =  "";


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST["imes"]) && !empty($_POST["indeksbr"])){



    $ime= $_POST["imes"];
    $prezime= $_POST["prezimes"];
    $indeksbr= $_POST["indeksbr"];
    $izpredmet= $_POST["izpredmet"];
    $teorija= $_POST["teorija"];
    $zadaci=  $_POST["zadaci"];
    $akt = $_POST["akt"];
    $pris= $_POST["pris"];
    $semrad= $_POST["semrad"];
    $domrad= $_POST["domrad"];


    $query= "INSERT INTO evid_record(imes,prezimes,indeksbr, predmet, teorija, zadaci, akt, pris, semrad, domrad) 
             VALUES ('$ime', '$prezime','$indeksbr','$izpredmet', '$teorija', '$zadaci', '$akt', '$pris', '$semrad', '$domrad')";





     $execute=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($execute){
            $uspehupis = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
  <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
  <strong>Registracija uspesna!</strong></div>";

    }
}
    else{

        $NEuspehupis = "<div class='alert alert-danger fade in alert-dismissible'>
  <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
  <strong>Morate uneti ime,prezime, email i sifru!</strong></div>";



}

  $query1 ="UPDATE evid_record SET `ukupno` = (teorija + zadaci + akt + pris + semrad + domrad)";

    $execute1=mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

}






?>
```

Comment: 1) `$izpredmet= $_POST["izpredmet"];`...but in your form you have `<select name="zpredmet">`. The names don't match, so `$_POST["izpredmet"];` will never contain any value. 2) `<option name="izpredmet"` is invalid - individual options don't have names, they are not form fields. 3) `<option value=\"\"` you are making all the values of your options blank, so even when you do submit the field correctly there will be no value provided. You need to set a suitable value (maybe an ID?) in the "value" attribute of the option.

Comment: P.S. you are horrendously vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should [learn how to write your queries safely](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid malicious attackers from stealing, corrupting or deleting your data.

Comment: 1) Yea, I noticed that the names dont match("zpredmet") I've changed that but still nothing.

2) I also deleted that, still nothing..

3) I kinda found that part of the code online, so I'm not completely understanding that part. Also, I have never used IDs before. You have some link about them I can find useful?

I am aware of SQL injection attacks, but it doesnt really matter for this project(since its for my very old fashioned Pofessor hehe )

Comment: " I am aware of SQL injection attacks, but it doesnt really matter for this project" ok but it's still better to get into good habits for the future. Plus it can prevent other issues such as certain types of syntax error in the SQL (due to unescaped values - e.g. if one of your fields input values contains a single quote mark (`'`) then it will screw up your SQL string, but parameterised queries will take that problem away by escaping the inputs properly)

Comment: Regarding IDs...doesn't your "evidall" table have a primary key (like an ID) to go with the name? And normally it's that ID (and not the name itself) that you would insert into the evid_record table, if you have a proper foreign key relationship set up. Therefore it's the ID that you would need to pass to PHP when the form is submitted. And therefore it's that ID which you should put in the `<option` tag inside `value=""` - then when the user selects the name, the form records the selected ID, and submits that to the PHP.

Comment: If you don't have a proper ID, and you are wanting to insert the actual name into the evid_record table then a) that's a bad, de-normalised database design and you should change it, but b) you could solve the problem of no values being submitted by doing `echo "<option value=\"".$datarows['epredmet']."\">" . $datarows['epredmet'] . "</option>";` so that the name becomes the value (as well as the description). (You need to understand that in a `<select`> the _value_ of the seleted option is submitted with the form data, not the _description_ which the user sees.)

Comment: I tried the code @ADyson wrote me in the last comment, and it works like a charm! Ah ofc I have the ids in the table, i thought the IDs You were talking about are something else. 

Since its working perfectly, if You want to post it as a answer so I can up vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1) `$izpredmet= $_POST["izpredmet"];` ...but in your form you have `<select name="zpredmet">`. The names don't match, so `$_POST["izpredmet"]`; will never contain any value.

2) `<option name="izpredmet"` is invalid - individual options don't have names, they are not form fields, so remove the "name" attribute from here

3) `<option value=\"\"` you are making all the values of your options blank, so even when you do submit the field correctly there will be no value provided - the form will submit an empty string as the selected value. You need to set a suitable value in the "value" attribute of the option. If you don't have a separate ID to be used as the value, you can just write

```
echo "<option value=\"".$datarows['epredmet']."\">" . $datarows['epredmet'] . "</option>";
```